# Error running Karma from Electron Angular project

Tags: angular, electron, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I have trying many many configurations unsuccessfully. The one detailed below, throws an error when I am executing `karma start`.
`arma plugin is meant to be used from within Angular CLI and will not work correctly outside of it`

At project level I have this karma.config.js

`module.exports = require('./src/karma.conf.js');`

that is pointing to this configuration:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-electron'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client:{
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, '../coverage'),
      reports: [ 'html', 'lcovonly' ],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['AngularElectron'],
    singleRun: true,
    customLaunchers: {
      AngularElectron: {
        base: 'Electron',
        browserWindowOptions: {
          webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            allowRunningInsecureContent: true
          }
        }
      }
    },
    client: {
      useIframe: false
    }
  });
};
```

My package.json is visible from https://github.com/twolfson/karma-electron/issues/43

What should I change?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I checked out the issue on GH, and your immediate problem is that you need to use `ng test`, but there's another key detail not covered by the docs that you might need to know to get karma-electron working with the Angular/Jasmine stack (I just worked this out):

1. The `var fs = require('fs')` in electron's index.js will fail to resolve without a custom webpack.config.js

   a. run an `npm i @angular-builders/custom-webpack -D`

   b. In your angular.json, modify your test project:

   `"test": {
         "builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:karma",
         "options": {
           ...
           "customWebpackConfig": {
             "path": "./webpack.config.js"
           }
         }
       }`

   c. Add a webpack.config.js at the project root with this inside:

   `module.exports = {
        target: 'electron-renderer'
      };`

   This will enable require functionality.

Comment: the next exception is launched: **An unhandled exception occurred: Job name "..getProjectMetadata" does not exist.,** any idea about this?